# Problem reprojecting UTM zones

Tags: python, coordinate-system, utm

I am new in programming with maps and coordinates, I am making a software on python where I load a raster (in UTM 18S that extent up to 19S, south orientation ) and a Landsat8 (orientation north), if the Landsat image is on UTM 18S and inside the raster limits; between PATH 5-9 and ROW 60-68; I can overlap both image and have a good coordinate alignment [image: as seen on image, left: raster, right: landsat]

The problem appears when I try to use a landsat that is on UTM 19S, I reproject it with `pyproj` library and the projections from the metadata, checked on QGIS and the coordinates are correct:

```
p1 = Proj(proj='utm', zone=19,datum='WGS84')
p2 = Proj(proj="utm", zone=18,datum='WGS84')

UL_X_PRODUCT = 122700.000
UL_Y_PRODUCT = -204000.000

UR_X_PRODUCT = 350400.000
UR_Y_PRODUCT = -204000.000

LL_X_PRODUCT = 122700.000
LL_Y_PRODUCT = -436500.000

LR_X_PRODUCT = 350400.000
LR_Y_PRODUCT = -436500.000

a1,b1=transform(p1, p2, UL_X_PRODUCT, UL_Y_PRODUCT)
a2,b2=transform(p1, p2, UR_X_PRODUCT, UR_Y_PRODUCT)
a3,b3=transform(p1, p2, LL_X_PRODUCT, LL_Y_PRODUCT)
a4,b4=transform(p1, p2, LR_X_PRODUCT, LR_Y_PRODUCT)
```

result (added 10 million to be oriented in south orientation):

```
UL X, Y, (1e7+Y):  790329.086988 -203853.453007 9796146.54699
UR X, Y, (1e7+Y):  1018292.89036 -204622.506814 9795377.49319
LL X, Y, (1e7+Y):  789100.325377 -436182.202764 9563817.79724
LR X, Y, (1e7+Y):  1017056.67578 -437826.672301 9562173.3277
```

but in the software I get a misaligment, checked the ecuation of conversion to get from UTM2pixel and viceversa and are correct, ,the yellow box is where the center mass of the red polygon should be.
[image: test on landsat 19S]

Is there any other good library to reproject UTM zones? 
Could the misalligment be due to reprojection error correction? I understand that a coordinate that is near the limit, can be different from 18S and 19S.

Comment: A reprojection is not a simple translation of the array. Check tools like `reproject` in the `rasterio.warp` module, to reproject your data. [documentation](https://mapbox.github.io/rasterio/topics/reproject.html).

Comment: Already downloaded library but stuck on a problem trying to convert, rasterio doesn't accept the CRS I am choosing: 'epsg:32718'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after weeks trying, my problem was that I only reprojected points, so the coordinates I took where the correct but the Landsat image was still the same, I had to reproject all the map to UTM 18S, tried some `rasterio` code, but got an error due to GDAL enviroment variable was wrong declared on system, fixed it and applied this [code](https://jgomezdans.github.io/gdal_notes/reprojection.html) with `GDAL` library and WORKED! Image 1 was only reprojecting points, image 2 is after reprojecting all image landsat

[image: Image 1: wrong]

[image: Image 2: correct]