# How to reproject landsat with GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, coordinate-system, utm, landsat-8

I had read posts where give to solution to reprojectin using GDAL but is always like this:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=21.16666666666667 +lon_0=-158 \
            +k=0.999990 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs' \
            input_raster.tif output_raster.tif
```

or this:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:2784 input_raster.tif output_raster.tif
```

but I want to make it on script to add it to my code, not just putting on console, and haven't found any documentation about that.

Also, what are the input parameters exactly? I am trying to reproject Landsat images from UTM 19N to UTM 18S,
the proj4.string I have are:

```
p1 = Proj("+proj=utm +zone=19 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m  ")    #Input projection
p2 = Proj("+proj=utm +zone=18 +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m ")  #output projection
```

EDIT: I am working on Python 2.7

Comment: Maybe you could be a bit more detailed on what code/language you're talking about

Comment: Sorry, already added, on python 2.7

Comment: UTM 18S = EPSG:32718, so what is the problem with the second command you provided ? UPDATE: okay, python .... necessary piece of information ;-)

Comment: my question is how to use gdalwarp on script to implement on my code, not on command console as the first code seems like

Comment: With python 2.7, you can use **os** module to run **gdalwarp**  command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already find the solution, answer is [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242972/problem-reprojecting-utm-zones/244858#244858) that I post in other post of mine

Answer (score 1):

With python 2.7, you can use next code:

```
import os

source_path = " -of GTiff " + "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/tiznados_canoa_part.tif"
target_path = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/tiznados_canoa_part_reproj.tif"

source_proj = "\'+proj=utm +zone=19 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m  \' "
new_proj = "+proj=utm +zone=18 +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m "
target_proj = " -t_srs " + '\''+ new_proj + '\''

cmd = "gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs " + \
                        source_proj + \
                        target_proj + \
                        source_path + \
                        " " + \
                        target_path

print cmd

os.system(cmd)
```

I tried it out at the Python Console of QGIS with a raster projected in UTM/19 N. At next image, metadata of resulting raster is pointed out that its projection was produced as expected.

[image]

Comment: why you put ¨" -of GTiff "¨?

Comment: mmm tried it on Pycharm and got this error:
ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:
'+proj=utm

Also tried it on python console of QGIS, no error but in the target file got no TIF image

Comment: **UPDATE**:  fixed erasing the `( \' )` on the lines,  but now new error: `ERROR 4: +zone=19: No such file or directory`

Comment: Use copy/paste and adapt to your paths where it corresponds.

Comment: Done that, still error :(