# Error reprojecting Landsat with rasterio

Tags: python, coordinate-system, landsat, utm, rasterio

I am trying to reproject on python 2.7 a Landsat8 image from UTM 19N to UTM 18S using rasterio, reading the docs I found and example on the [documentation](https://mapbox.github.io/rasterio/topics/reproject.html) and just change the input, output file and dst_CRS:

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from rasterio.warp import calculate_default_transform, reproject, RESAMPLING

INPUT_raster_1 = "D:\Minam\LC08_L1TP_005063_20170528_20170528_01_RT\LC08_L1TP_005063_20170528_20170528_01_RT_B5.tif"
dst_crs ='EPSG:32718' #output reprojection

with rasterio.open("D:\Minam\LC08_L1TP_005063_20170528_20170528_01_RT\LC08_L1TP_005063_20170528_20170528_01_RT_B5.tif") as src:
    affine, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
        src.crs, dst_crs, src.width, src.height, *src.bounds)
    kwargs = src.meta.copy()
    kwargs.update({
        'crs': dst_crs,
        'transform': affine,
        'affine': affine,
        'width': width,
        'height': height
    })

    with rasterio.open('D:\Minam\wgs84.tif', 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
        for i in range(1, src.count + 1):
            reproject(
                source=rasterio.band(src, i),
                destination=rasterio.band(dst, i),
                src_transform=src.affine,
                src_crs=src.crs,
                dst_transform=affine,
                dst_crs=dst_crs,
                resampling=RESAMPLING.nearest)
```

The first problem is that there is no module RESAMPLING on library, then this when reading the dst_crs:

**`rasterio.errors.CRSError: Invalid CRS: 'EPSG:32718'`**

But that is the epsg to utm 18S. How do I fix it?

Comment: Documentation actually has "dst_crs = {'init': 'EPSG:3857'}". Try changing to that format with 'EPSG:32718'.

Comment: still the same error: 'rasterio.errors.CRSError: Invalid CRS: CRS({'init': 'EPSG:3857'})' or EPSG:32718

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'invalid CRS' error indicates to me that GDAL can't find an EPSG database file. See https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQInstallationAndBuilding#WhatisGDAL_DATAenvironmentvariable for how to set the `GDAL_DATA` environment variable.

For warping, I suggest this new Rasterio feature (based on a well-known GDAL feature): https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/virtual-warping.html. It's easier to use than the less abstracted `reproject()` function.

Comment: You were right, on this machine someone was previously installed GDAL for windows but the environment variable was wrong configurated, re-did it and try reprojecting (but using GDAL) check answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242972/problem-reprojecting-utm-zones/244858#244858)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem:

`rasterio.errors.CRSError: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv. Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.`

After much testing and an error I arrived at the root of my problem: `GDAL` was installed through `Anaconda` while `rasterio` through `pip`

The solution: uninstall `rasterio` from `pip` and install it from `Anaconda`.