# Resolving CRS Error in rasterio

Tags: python, coordinate-system, rasterio

I am trying to use the pysheds package to calculate flow accumulation from a DEM. However, when reading the DEM `.tif`-file, I get the following error. I can't find any more information as to what this means. My code is as follows:

```
home_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
test_file = os.path.join(home_dir, r"N040W010_N045W005\repr-N042W006_AVE_DSM.tif")
grid = Grid.from_raster(test_file, data_name='dem')
plotFigure(grid.dem, 'Elevation (m)')
```

The error I get is this:

> CRSError: Invalid CRS input: CRS({'init': 'epsg:32630'})

I would love to mean what this means, I have changed the projection from a global to a local one, but with the global projection, I had the same error.

Comment: Check this thread [Error reprojecting Landsat with rasterio](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243976/error-reprojecting-landsat-with-rasterio)

Comment: Thanks, so I should set the GDAL_DATA environment variable? But it's already set, how do I know for sure that the correct .csv file is in the folder? I do have the gcs.csv and pcs.csv files.